# Kendo MVC Grid Data Annotations

Tags: kendo-ui

I Have a solution that used Telerik Grids and we opt to upgrade to Kendo.

But now, Kendo doesn't seem to respect the row's model data annotations for Required, Regular Expressions, etc, on validations.

Anyone can explain if this is how they work or if it is a problem of my own doing?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the data annotation attributes should work the same way as they worked with the old MVC extensions. Pick this project and give a try.

http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/custom-popup-editor.aspx